Parsing sentence 逃げまくってたんですけど
I was listening to a story about a girl who was getting followed up several flights of stairs. She said 逃げまくってたんですけど after which presumably means she was running away from the guy, but im confused on how this sentence is being formed. What is the まくって　part of this sentence?

逃げ is continuative form (連用形) of 逃げる.
まくって is te-form of auxiliary verb or suffix まくる (Jisho, Wiktionary) (spelling with kanji would be 捲る, but unlikely to be used for this usage as auxiliary verb / suffix), which means "to do over and over again; to do relentlessly; to do with reckless abandon; to do continuously".
So 逃げまくる means "to run away over and over again / relentlessly / continuously".
Following た is abbreviated form of いた (past tense of auxiliary verb いる), and ん is abbreviated form of の (nominalizer).

Thanks couldnt find まくる in my dictionary. appreciate it
